# Expo React-native is caching contents without updating even after hot reloading on android emulator/physical-device?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

**Solved now after restarting pc**

I am building a photo-feed application in React-native, using expo on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS,

even after reloading using `CTRL + M > Reload`, it doesn't take any effects after changes in files.

I stopped it and again restarted.

I have to close the entire terminal to see new changes in files.

I updated code as `"username clicked is ="`, but in terminal, it shows only old output,

[image: screenshot]

also, in terminal it updated `this.state.username` , but when I displayed it in `<Text>` Component, it shows it's old value.

it is not updating a value on the emulator though just one line above it gives correct value to a terminal.

[image: screenshot2]

[GitHub link](https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/exchange-o-gram/commits/master) of project is
contents of package.json are

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.9.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am running watchman before running emulator using bash file as,

```
touch .watchmanconfig
watchman watch-del-all
watchman shutdown-server
sudo pkill -9 -x fseventsd
echo fs.inotify.max_user_instances=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
echo fs.inotify.max_queued_events=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: Please share your code which you used to store value into state.